# Wordpress get_bloginfo('template_directory') returns hostname instead of website url

Tags: php, wordpress

A Wordpress theme that I have installed doesn't display some images because they can't be resolved. Relative links work, however when the above phpcode is used it uses my internal hostname(not fqdn)The error I receive is:

Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found:

```
"http://dove/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Avada/images/logo.png"
```

I'm trying to understand why it doesn't just use the website url that I configured so lookup the template directory and any resources needed. How can I workaround this? 
dove is my hostname but not my external website url that I access Wordpress from.
Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right, it should be doing that. I don't think you need to use `get_bloginfo();` though, unless you plan on doing something with its contents.

Use `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>` to return your site url.

Or simply use `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` to return your template location.

For a full list of what you can used with `bloginfo`, check the Codex. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Comment: but according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo#Template_Directory it should be return a full url. Now it's just returning my hostname that's why it can't find the resource. I'm a beginner at Wordpress, maybe I'm interpreting it wrong.

Comment: Just output it, and don't get with `get_bloginfo($show);`, instead just use `bloginfo($show)`.

Comment: I installed the same theme on another vm and it worked without me editing the theme's php code. I didn't want to edit code from a theme I didn't create myself. I guess I have some weird dns resolution issue that I have to troubleshoot. Thanks a lot for the tips!

Comment: Check your database and wp-config maybe? It stores 2 instances in the database as far as I recall, but that is very weird. http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 0):

Small correction... one needs to add echo.

```
<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>
```